# <br>? \n? a line break in java

Tags: java, swing

I have three JLabels and three JTextAreas. I have them in borderlayout, center, but I want each of them in a different line, that's not happening and the top ten search results in Google for line break java don't solve the problem. How can I do a simple line break?

Comment: can you show how you are adding your components to your JPanel?

Comment: mainPanel.add(aLabel);
    mainPanel.add(aScroller);
    mainPanel.add(bLabel);
    mainPanel.add(bScroller);
    mainPanel.add(cLabel);
    mainPanel.add(cScroller);

Comment: It worked like this:

mainPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(mainPanel, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If this is a Swing application, you should use a [layout manager](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/layout/using.html) to position your fields in the container.

Answer (score 2):

Line break won't help with placing Swing objects; you need to place a layout on a center JPanel. That is, the center of your border layout should be a single Swing object, a JPanel, and you should set that to a style which allows you to stack each widget. GridLayout(6,1) may do it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use layout managers like [GridLayout](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/GridLayout.html) or [GridBagLayout](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/GridBagLayout.html). Even though the latter one is only recommended for code generated by GUI generators I prefer it because it gives me the most flexibility.

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
GridBagLayout layout = new GridBagLayout();
panel.setLayout(layout);
layout.add(label1, new GridBagConstraints(0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, GridBagConstraints.CENTER, GridBagConstraints.BOTH, new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0), 0, 0));
layout.add(area1, new GridBagConstraints(1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, GridBagConstraints.CENTER, GridBagConstraints.BOTH, new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0), 0, 0));
layout.add(label2, new GridBagConstraints(0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, GridBagConstraints.CENTER, GridBagConstraints.BOTH, new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0), 0, 0));
layout.add(area2, new GridBagConstraints(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, GridBagConstraints.CENTER, GridBagConstraints.BOTH, new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0), 0, 0));
layout.add(label3, new GridBagConstraints(0, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, GridBagConstraints.CENTER, GridBagConstraints.BOTH, new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0), 0, 0));
layout.add(area3, new GridBagConstraints(1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, GridBagConstraints.CENTER, GridBagConstraints.BOTH, new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0), 0, 0));
panel.add(label1);
panel.add(label2);
panel.add(label3);
panel.add(area1);
panel.add(area2);
panel.add(area3);
```

Of course this looks butt-ugly but should get you started.

You can also abuse a [BorderLayout](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/BorderLayout.html):

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
JPanel topRow = new JPanel();
panel.add(topRow, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
topRow.add(label1);
topRow.add(area1);
JPanel middleRowBox = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
panel.add(middleRowBox, BorderLayout.CENTER);
JPanel middleRow = new JPanel();
middleRowBox.add(middleRow, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
middleRow.add(label2);
middleRow.add(area2);
JPanel bottomRowBox = new JPanel();
middleRowBox.add(bottomRowBox, BorderLayout.CENTER);
JPanel bottomRow = new JPanel();
bottomRowBox.add(bottomRow, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
bottomRow.add(label3);
bottomRow.add(area3);
bottomRowBix.add(new JPanel(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

Comment: After building a LOT of UI components, I only use GridBagLayout anymore - yes it is a little more work, but you can be guaranteed if you do things right that your view will scale appropriately.

Comment: After building a LOT of UI components, we don't use GridBagLayout anymore - yes, it gives you some nice cell scaling and alignment options, but there's nothing you can't do with some panels with simpler LayoutManagers and refactoring can be a pain. And if you do things wrong you can spend an hour finding a singular false setting.

Answer (score 1):

Try using a GridLayout for starters:

```
panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(0,2));
// the order of added components is important
panel.add(labelA);
panel.add(textAreaA);
panel.add(labelB);
panel.add(textAreaB);
...
```

Doesn't look too pretty but it gets you started.

If you don't set a LayoutManager to a new panel, it will use a FlowLayout which behaves somewhat like HTML layout. But there is no such thing as an intended line break in a FlowLayout. It will just put component after component until it reaches the end of the available space and then start a new row.
If you want control over your layouts - don't use FlowLayout.

Layout managers you might want to get to know are:

- BorderLayout - very good if you want resizeable content
- GridLayout - simple equals width and height grid
- null - allows you to use setBounds on each component to get absolute positions

There are more, but these three should allow you to layout 95% of your panels.